# Need to create a persistence session in python using mechanize browser instance

Tags: python, session-cookies, mechanize

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
import time
import cookielib
import requests

username = 'user@gmail.com'   # your username/email
password = 'pwd'   # your password

br = mechanize.Browser()

# browser settings (used to emulate a browser)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_debug_http(False)
br.set_debug_responses(False)
br.set_debug_redirects(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open('https://sso.openx.com/login/login') # open twitter

br.select_form(nr=0) # select the form

br['email'] = username
br['password'] = password
br.submit() # submit the login data
    # set cookies
cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookies)
print cookies
temp_jar=br.set_cookiejar(cookies)

print(br.response().read()) # print the response

br1=mechanize.Browser()
br1.set_cookiejar(cookies)
br1.set_handle_robots(False)
r=br1.open('http://ox-ui.admin.one97adworks.com/ox/3.0/a/report/run?&report_format=json&end_date=2013-06-01&report=order_perf&do_break=&rollup=hourly&start_date=2013-06-01')
print r.text
```

basically i have 2 URL's I have to login in first("https://sso.openx.com/login/login") only
after logging in with correct credentials i will have access to the other url ("http://ox-ui.admin.one97adworks.com/ox/3.0/a/report/run?&report_format=json&end_date=2013-06-01&report=order_perf&do_break=&rollup=hourly&start_date=2013-06-01")
and i have to fetch the json returned by the URL

So basically i want a persistent session with which i can login and then access the other url i am able to login successfully but haven't been able to call the other url using the same session or cookies or any other persistence method between the two calls

Comment: Are you required to create another mechanize browser instance?

Comment: no thats not required but it ain't working in the same instance also

Answer (score 0):

Try to define cookiejar **before** you open the web page. And use only one instance of mechanize